# unplugged hdd, now boots to windows instead of refind

Tags: arch-linux, windows, dual-boot, refind

I have an SSD that I wanted Windows on, so I could either dual boot with Arch Linux on my HDD or use the SSD in a VM.

I had `refind` with Windows 10, and Arch Linux installed. I disconnected the power and data (or whatever the data cable is) to the HDD and connected a separate SATA 3 and power cable to my SSD. I previously had wiped the SSD through Arch Linux.

I then booted to a Windows installation USB drive and installed Windows 10 on the SSD, which went fine.

I then unplugged the SSD and replugged the HDD with Arch Linux and Windows to ensure it worked fine. The issue was that I booted straight to Windows 10 and updated. I now can't get it to boot into `refind`.

I checked, and the Arch Linux partitions are all still there and okay.

I'm not sure how unplugging and replugging my HDD messed up `refind` as my computer was entirely off and had the power cable disconnected. I don't believe I disconnected power when I unplugged the SSD and replugged the HDD (an error on my part).

Does anyone know what caused this and how I could fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using an arch live boot and reinstalling refind. This was a very simple solution and I suppose unplugging the HDD caused the windows bootloader to reset or update for some reason. Hopefully this question can still help someone, though it's very specific and the level of skill to be doing this stuff means you'll likely find out the solution on your own.

Comment: Or you could have used `efibootmgr` instead